# c# Static Analysis for static methods that modify a provided reference object

Tags: c#, static-analysis

Imagine I have a static class that has a collection of helper functions. I'm attempting to figure out if the contract of these helper functions are strictly input/output or if they have side effects. Is there a good way to do this analysis in an automated way?

For example if I had

```
//I would not expect to see this show up as causing a side effect        
public static decimal GetRetailValue(ExpressionContext context, object[] validationParameters)
{
     if (context == null)
     {
          return 0;
     }
     return 5;
}

//I would expect to see context.CarValue show up as a side effect of the method     
public static decimal GetRetailValueOfCarToday(ExpressionContext context, object[] validationParameters)
{
     if (context == null)
     {
          if(context.carValueToday != null)
          {
               context.CarValue = context.CarValueToday;
          }
          return context.CarValue;
     }
     return 5;
}
```

Comment: Not built-in, no. You could possibly [write your own analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix.md), but you also gotta be careful with things like `void Process(Context ctx) => ctx.Items.Clear()` where you have an indirect side effect from a deeper property/method chain.